# Make a block element take up space

Tags: html, css

I have some block elements which i have stacked with one block being longer than the others http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/ct7aA/2/show/

The would like the red div to take up space on top.How would i make the red div take up the space without necessarily using the negative `margin-bottom` to push it up?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ct7aA/3/

Trick was to add position:relative to container div, and position absolute to red div

```
.top_div{
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}

.red{
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
    background-color:red;
    margin-left:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```